# ability to insist on specific "willing to relocate to"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, location, employers

When doing an employer search for people in my area, if I have the box checked to include people who are willing to relocate to my area, I get lots of people who are willing to relocate, apparently, anywhere in the United States.  However, I don't necessarily believe that this means that they will specifically be willing to relocate to my town.  Can we have the option to exclude people who are matching because they're willing to relocate to an entire country, so we can focus the matches more precisely?

That is, if I'm in New York, I'd be happy to see people who want to relocate to New York, or to the East Coast of the US, or to the tri-state area, or whatever, but I'd like to exclude people who indicated the entire USA.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary because it is generally understood that if you are serious about a position, that you would be willing to relocate wherever the job takes you. It's typically just a pre-screen.

Comment: I don't agree, actually.  My guess is that, when people say that they're willing to relocate to "United States", what they really mean is that they'd relocate either for 1) a good job in a place they'd like to be anyway, or 2) a great job in a place they don't really want to be.  I'd like to be able to narrow my search results to just the people who actually want to be in my area, rather than just wanting a job somewhere.

Comment: @JacobM: That would be kind of difficult. I could see if maybe you said a region, but to have the user say they don't want to live in this city or that city is probably too difficult. While there are cities I wouldn't live in, I would work in them so I could see driving 20 mins from another city. Yes, I relocated but not to your town as you said, but I still relocated. So I think this is something that is not solvable in the way you propose. Maybe if you said, something like "Willing to relocate to West Coast, East Coast, etc" but not a county or city.

Comment: Really, all I want is the ability to NOT see people who are only matching because they said they would relocate to the United States.  Any subset of the United States (that matches) is fine.

Comment: @JacobM: So no international candidates, is what I gather? That would make sense to me.

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of people who are in the US now -- e.g. their current location is Texas or whatever -- and they say "willing to relocate to United States" so they're matching my search.  I'd like to exclude them.  Also, I can imagine someone in another country who would prefer to relocate to some part of the United States rather than anywhere in the US.  It's a big country.  :)

Comment: @JacobM: Sounds to me like its a matter of semantics. There probably are people who would move anywhere in the US. It should probably read "willing to relocate anywhere in the US". For me, I would be willing to relocate to NJ only so it would be beneficial to have the State listd.

Comment: This gets hard as I am willing to relocate but only if all the costs are paid AND there is a good job for my wife she can start at the saem time in the same town with T&C at least as good as her job!  (And we must be able to aford the type of housing we want with a good comute to each job) - now try and match on this!

Comment: @Ian -- indeed.  In a sense, perhaps, what I really want is to eliminate people who are merely willing to relocate but include people who are actually planning to relocate to my area.  That might not be many people, of course.